# Can jacksons ObjectMapper serialize Java-null as empty String, in Version 2.11.2

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind, objectmapper

I'm using the `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper` in `jackson-databind 2.11.2` and trying to serialize Java properties with `null`-value to something like this:

```
{ %Key% : "" }
```

I've tried:

```
ObjectMapper MAPPER = new JodaMapper();
        
DefaultSerializerProvider defaultSerializerProvider = new DefaultSerializerProvider.Impl();

defaultSerializerProvider.setNullValueSerializer(new JsonSerializer<Object>() {
   @Override
   public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
      gen.writeString("bla");
   }
});

MAPPER.setSerializerProvider(defaultSerializerProvider);
```

But the NullValueSerializers serialize-method does not get triggered for any fields.

Has anybody some ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution.... I had

```
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
```

at class level in the class that I wanted to serialize. When I remove the annotation I the code above works.

Answer (score 1):

There are a couple of ways to achieve custom null value serialising:

1. If you want to serialise a null as an empty String, try using this annotation on a property, or setter:

   ```
    @JsonSetter(nulls=Nulls.AS_EMPTY)
   ```

or the same for specific mapper:

```
MAPPER.configOverride(String.class).setSetterInfo(JsonSetter.Value.forValueNulls(Nulls.AS_EMPTY));
```

2. You can initialise properties with default values on the declaration or in the getter.
3. As you've already mentioned, by providing a custom serialiser.

I did try your code, and that serialised null value as expected when using an ObjectMapper instead of JodaMapper. Is there any particular reason for using a JodaMapper?